Do we need a memory acquire barrier for one-shot spinlocks?
For locks (spin locks, mutex), we usually need to add acquire fence when locking to ensure the functionality of the lock.
But is this necessary for one-shot spin locks? For example:
int val = 0;
atomic_int lock = 0;

void thread0(void)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    if (atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(&lock, &tmp, 1, memory_order_relaxed, memory_order_relaxed)) { // do we need memory_order_acquire here ?
        assert(!val); // will it always success?
        val = 1;
    }
}

// same as thread0
void thread1(void)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    if (atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(&lock, &tmp, 1, memory_order_relaxed, memory_order_relaxed)) {
        assert(!val);
        val = 1;
    }
}

More specifically, is the following code correct on the armv7-a architecture(There may be some differences from the C code mentioned above):
val:
    .long 0
lock:
    .long 0

core0:
    mov r0, #val
    mov r1, #lock
    mov r4, #1
2:
    ldrex r2, [r1]
    cmp r2, #0
    beq 1f
    bx  lr  // ret
1:
    strex r3, r4, [r1]
    cmp r3, #0
    bne 2b

    // without acquire fence
    ldr r5, [r0] // is r5 != 0 allowed?



core1:
    mov r0, #val
    mov r1, #lock
    mov r4, #1
2:
    ldrex r2, [r1]
    cmp r2, #0
    beq 1f
    bx  lr  // ret
1:
    strex r3, r4, [r1]
    cmp r3, #0
    bne 2b

    dmb ish  // acquire fence
    str r4, [r0]  // store 1

A more specific example (do work and do clean should not have race) :
#define EXIT_FLAG 1
#define WORK_FLAG 2

atomic_int state = 0;

void thread0(void)
{
    int tmp;
    while (1) {
        tmp = 0;
        if (!atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(&state, &tmp, WORK_FLAG, memory_order_relaxed, memory_order_relaxed)) { // do we need acquire here?
            assert(tmp == EXIT_FLAG);
            return;
        }

        // do work

        tmp = WORK_FLAG;
        if (!atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(&state, &tmp, 0, memory_order_release, memory_order_relaxed)) {
            assert(tmp == (EXIT_FLAG | WORK_FLAG));
            // do the clean
            return;
        }
    }
}

void thread1(void)
{
    int tmp = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(&state, &tmp, tmp | EXIT_FLAG, memory_order_acquire, memory_order_relaxed)) // we need acquire here to fit with release in thread0
            break;
    }

    if (!(tmp & WORK_FLAG)) {
        // do the clean
    }
}


You need _Atomic int lock;.  Otherwise the code shown is okay, since only one thread will access val,.  But this assumes that no other part of the program accesses val, which is probably not a correct assumption, since why are you bothering to write to val if nobody will ever read it?  So you need to show how all other accesses to val would be protected against data race.

@NateEldredge I have added a practical example to demonstrate how to protect variables and prevent competition

This section is about the first code block, where both threads do
if (lock.CAS_strong(0, 1, relaxed)){ assert(val==0); val=1; }
The assert (in the first code block) always succeeds because only one thread or the other ever runs the if body, and it's sequenced before the val=1 in the same thread.
The atomic RMW decides which wins the race to be that thread, but it doesn't need to sync with any previous writer to prevent overlap of their "critical sections".  (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/)
You don't have a critical section.  The load of val could have happened before the CAS, but that would still be fine because you'd still load the initial value then.  And there's no release store so nothing lets other threads know that your val update is complete.
I wouldn't call it a one-shot spinlock, that has potentially misleading implications like that you'll sync-with the lock variable and that other threads can see when you're done.  (BTW, lock needs to bet atomic_int aka _Atomic int not plain int.)
This is a bit like a guard variable for a non-constant initializer for a static variable which is one-shot for the whole program, although that actually does still need acquire, unfortunately, unless you can separate the case where one thread very recently finished init vs. cases where we've already synced-with the init.  Maybe a third value for the guard variable and something like a global all-threads membarrier() system call that runs itself on all cores / threads.

Second code block
The new code has one thread running an infinite loop around try_lock() / do work / unlock.  The other thread spinning on a CAS(acquire) to set another bit that will make the first thread stop, and to sync with its release store.
But there are no shared variables other than atomic_int state;, so there's no difference between relaxed and release/acquire.  Operations on a single object don't reorder with each other within the same thread even for relaxed.  seq_cst would forbid store-forwarding where one thread sees its own stores before they're globally visible (to all threads).
The first loop will exit (via one if or the other) on the first failed CAS_strong.  So as soon as the second thread succeeds at its CAS to set the second bit.
This isn't a locking algorithm: the second thread can succeed at setting EXIT_FLAG while the first thread is inside its "critical section", i.e. while WORK_FLAG is set in state.  No strengthening of the memory_order parameter to any of the operations can change this.
Without acquire in the first thread's CAS which "takes the lock" (setting WORK_FLAG), later operations can become visible to other threads before state changes.  That's a problem for a normal lock, but this is far enough from being a lock that it's not obvious what exactly do work and do the clean are supposed to be.
Only one thread will run do the clean; either the first or second thread depending on when the second thread succeeds at a CAS.

I add critical sections now

@untitled: updated my answer accordingly.  That's pretty much a different question; none of the special-case factors apply.  Your second code block is just doing a normal try_lock / unlock.

Oh, I'm very sorry, I made a huge mistake. In the last example, acquire must be used in thread1 to adapt to the release in thread 0, preventing race between do_clean and do_work. I have updated the problem description.

The key is whether to use 'acquire' in thread 0. I don't think it's necessary,
thread0:
atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(&state, &tmp,  WORK_FLAG, memory_order_relaxed, memory_order_relaxed);
thread1:
atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(&state, &tmp,  tmp | EXIT_FLAG, memory_order_acquire, memory_order_relaxed);
A disposable(one-shot is not suitable, so I changed a name) spinlock is formed between these two sentences. If thread1 successfully executes do_clean, then thread0 will not execute do_work/do_clean, just like the first example.

@untitled: Updated my answer.  I'm not sure what synchronization is needed since I don't know what do the clean does, whether it reads or writes any variables that are accessed earlier or later in the program.

Thank you for your patient answer. Considering the differences between the last complex example and the first example, I have decided to open a new question to discuss it. As for this question, in discussion with you and John, I think I already have an answer.


Do we need a memory acquire barrier for one-shot spinlocks?

TL;DR: Yes.
It looks like your "one-shot" is meant to describe a device in which you try only once to acquire the lock represented by an atomic object, possibly failing, instead of retrying until succeeding.  But retrying is what the "spin" part of "spinlock" describes, so your "one-shot spinlock" is an oxymoron.
The question seems odd in another way, too.  If you accept, as you seem to do, that you need acquire or stronger memory semantics on locking for a regular spinlock to have its intended effect (combined with release or stronger when unlocking), then why do you have any doubt about needing the same for your one-shot device?  After all, a regular spinlock might well succeed on its first locking attempt, and that's equivalent to the case where your one-shot device succeeds.  That the one-shot device might also fail does not suggest that it could get away with weaker memory semantics in the success case.
In particular, a release store by thread T1 ensures that all memory operations by T1 that happen before the store are visible in each thread T2 that performs an acquire load that observes the release store or another operation that happens after it.  Relaxed loads and stores do not provide those guarantees.  The memory ordering semantics are about the visibility of non-atomic memory operations, not about the visibility of accesses to the atomic object. There may be special cases where it makes sense to perform locking that does not provide memory-ordering semantics for non-atomic memory operations, but those are atypical.
You don't necessarily need a full barrier / fence per se, however.  At least in the C semantics.  You need only a release paired with an acquire on the lock object.  The C stdatomic functions do not assume that that will require fences, though it might be implemented with fences for a given target architecture.
The new issue in your one-shot case is what memory semantics you need or want when acquiring the lock fails.  Relaxed ordering should be fine for most purposes in the locking failure case, as you must then assume that it is unsafe to access any data protected by the lock anyway.  Moreover, the C interfaces do not allow you to specify release or acquire / release for the failure case, which makes sense because in that case, there is no store to the atomic object.  C does forbid the memory semantics being stronger than those for success, so with respect to the C interfaces, the only viable alternatives that avoid sequentially consistent ordering are acquire or acquire / release on success combined with acquire or relaxed on failure.
The weakest memory ordering that works for standard locking semantics is:
_Atomic int lock = 0;

/*
 * Attempts to acquire the lock, returning 1 on success and 0 on failure.
 * Success affects memory with acquire semantics.
 * Failure has relaxed memory semantics.
 */
_Bool try_lock(void) {
    int tmp = 0;
    return atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(
        &lock, &tmp, 1, memory_order_acquire, memory_order_relaxed);
}

/*
 * Unconditionally releases the lock, affecting memory with release
 * semantics.  Should be called only by a thread that currently holds
 * the lock.
 */
void release_lock(void) {
  atomic_store_explicit(&lock, 0, memory_order_release);
}


Very patient response, thank you very much. Some questions:

TL; DR: Yes. Does this answer include the first simple example? If so, it seems that your answer differs slightly from Peter Cordes, who said that the assert in the first example will always succeed.
If TL; DR: Yes. is the answer to the last complex example, I am very sorry for making a mistake here. I have updated the question, is it convenient for you to take a look?


@untitled, this answer does not conflict with Peter's.  Rather, it attempts to answer the question I take you to have meant, as conveyed by the question's title and quoted at the top of this answer. That is is somewhat different from the details conveyed by your first example, as you seem to have realized.  As Peter said, the assert in your first example will always succeed, but that's not related to the memory-ordering parameters of your atomic operations.

@untitled, the only edit I see since this answer was posted is to change the type of the lock variable from int to _Atomic int.  That's necessary, of course, but this answer was never hung up on that detail of the original code.  The example code here already makes the same correction without (previous) comment.

The last complex example has been modified by adding acquire in thread1

I see now, @untitled.  That was difficult to spot in the edit log, on account of the code being so much wider than the viewport.  But I still don't see how you think that might call for any changes to this answer.  To restate what I already wrote, if your lock is meant to guard access to non-atomic objects, then you need at least acquire memory ordering whenever you (successfully) lock it, and at least release memory ordering whenever you (successfully) unlock it.

——you need at least acquire memory ordering when you (successfully) lock it; why?
Imagine a scenario where a lot of threads trylock a lock, but once they do(trylock success), they will never release it, so only one will get the lock. Do I still need to acquire in this situation? What is the difference between this and the first example?

We need to acquire because there are releases from other threads, but what if the release doesn't exist? (No one executed unlock)

@untitled, if no thread that acquires the lock ever releases it, then "lock" isn't really the right term for the device. You gain nothing from acquire memory ordering in that case, but by the same token, you get protection of non-atomic objects only to the extent that you use the mechanism to avoid having any conflcting accesses to such objects in the first place.  That begs the question of why you want to bother with multiple threads and / or shared objects in such a case.

if no thread that acquires the lock ever releases it, then "lock" isn't really the right term for the device. You gain nothing from acquire memory ordering in that case OK, I think I already have an answer to this question. The above description is the meaning of the "one shot lock" that I originally intended to express. From this perspective, the answer should be TL; DR: NO.

Given that Peter's answer clearly states that the assert in the first example will not fail, I would choose his answer, but I still greatly appreciate your patient discussion with me. As for the last complex example, it is indeed different from this question. I have decided to open a new question to discuss.
